# How do I switch which display is primary?

Tags: unity, 11.10

Ever since I connected my HDTV to my Ubuntu system, Ubuntu has wanted to use it as the primary display.

I thought I had this fixed up through 11.04, but I do not remember how, and now with 11.10 the login box is showing up on the HDTV again.

This is a problem for me because normally the HDTV is (a) set to a different input source and (b) turned off.  Now I have to turn it on and change the input source every time I want to log in or launch an application.

How can I configure 11.10 to use the correct monitor as the primary?

Thank you.

Comment: Try turning off the secondary display(HDTV) in "Monitors" application, and turning it back again.

Answer (score 3):

First list all displays with:

```
xrandr --prop
```

Display names will look like `DVI-1`, `HDMI-0`, `VGA-1` and so on. Find the display you want to make primary and run the following command:

```
xrandr --output DVI-1 --primary
```

Where `DVI-1` is the display you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you switch the default display in Ubuntu's own display manager. It goes like this:

[image: Dash display settings]

However, **depending on your GPU driver you might need to use another application than the display manager** instead. Since I have an nVidia Graphics card for instance, the display manager won't work for me. I have to use the NVIDIA X Server Settings manager, shown in the picture below:

[image: Nvida Display Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ATI graphic card, I suggest you to manage primary screen by modifying [~/.config/monitors.xml](https://askubuntu.com/a/81016/32413)

[image]