# How can I force fullscreen on my right screen?

Tags: firefox, ati, multiple-monitors, streaming

I have 2 screens: 17" on left and 22" screen on right side.

[image: double screen]

When I watch a movie with VLC and want to watch on full-screen on my 22" screen (the right one), I move my VLC window in right screen and then click on full-screen => no problem.

[image: full-screen with vlc]

BUT when using Firefox and watching streaming video, watching on full-screen is always on 17" screen (left one).

[image: full-screen with firefox]

How can I force full-screen to be on my 22" screen (right one) ?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? :)

Comment: euh.. after checking my monitors.xml file, I ve seen that primary option was on left screen, I put it back to the right screen, reboot and finally the solution works, no more problem (till next time: I think that it is the application Mupen64 who is modifying this monitors.xml file when playing fullscreen)

Comment: What is the resolution of both screens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading severals questions about the subject "multiple-monitors", I've found the solution.
In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80114/need-to-reconfigure-absolute-position-of-dual-monitors-after-reboot-how-do-i-fi/80893#80893) I've discovered the existance of file `~/.config/monitors.xml`. (thank you "pamar84")
So I did this:

1. do a backup of this file `cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.xml-bkp`
2. open this file `gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml`
3. this file was containing 3 configurations !!! 
   So I did some cleaning:

   - I've found the configuration that I'm using and remove the 2 others.
   - also set my left screen to be the primary one.

Now with such nice `~/.config/monitors.xml` file, Firefox is not disoriented anymore and have the good behavior:
- when my window is left side and I choose full-screen => full-screen is left screen
- when my window is right side and I choose full-screen => full-screen is right screen

Here is the content of the cleaned `~/.config/monitors.xml` file:
[image]