# Dual Monitors Won't Work

Tags: ati, video, graphics, multiple-monitors, monitor

I am running version 12.04 LTS with the additional driver installed for my graphics card; HIS Radeon HD 5450 Silence 1GB DDR3 HDMI HDCP.

I have an LG (don't know model) and a Dell (also no model) attached to the DVI and VGA ports on the card, respectively.

When I go to "Displays" and turn on the Dell monitor, it's just blank.  I get an error about the resolution not being valid, or something to that effect.  I'm on my work Windows laptop right now so just let me know if the exact error would be helpful.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

T

Comment: yes, the exact error could help. Have also a look to my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/128862/32413

Answer (score 1):

I have an HD 5450 card with dual monitors.  Using the displays setting dialog will only work with the default open-source driver, which works pretty well for most things, although probably not for games.

If you use the added proprietary driver, then you need to use the AMD catalyst settings app - the one with administrative privileges is the only one that will change settings.  This app should be installed, and you can search for it in the applications.