# Second monitor full screen flash problem 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, flash

I occasionally plug in a second larger monitor to watch videos, what happens is that when I full screen the flash video it jumps to the width of both the screens put together and won't snap to the larger second screen.

Any ideas on how to get flash to work properly?

By the way I have Ubuntu 12.04 x64 on an ASUS K52N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when using Chrome. Chrome, unlike other browsers, does not use the Flash plugin installed on your system but its own embedded plugin.

The problem is that this version does not work well on Ubuntu 12.04 when using multiple screens. So you need to force Chrome to use the default system Flash installation (the one that you use in other browsers, e.g. in Firefox).

To do that:

1. Type `chrome://plugins` in the address bar
2. Click the button "details" on the right side of the screen.
3. At this point you will see two versions of the flash plugin:Disable the one that has the most recent number version.
4. Reload the page where the flash content is.

That should solve the problem.

Please note that you will still have the issue (which is different from the one you are experiencing) that full screen videos will always start in one of your monitors, regardless of where your Chrome window is located; just follow the link below to fix that.:

[How can I force fullscreen on my right screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80763/how-can-i-force-fullscreen-on-my-right-screen)